# Slack slash command results in different encoding coming from iOS app or MacOS App

Tags: ios, macos, slack, slack-api

We have a Slash command integration and discovered that the text passed to the slash command is encoded differently if it comes from the (iOS) mobile app compared to the Desktop app.

For the command "/whereis #xsd" on the MacOS Desktop app, the text element in the body is encoded as: `text=%3C%23C02MKG1LH%7Cxsd%3E`

For the command "/whereis #xsd" on the iOS app the text element in the body is encoded as: `text=%26lt%3B%23C02MKG1LH%7Cxsd%26gt%3B`

The iOS app is incorrect.

Did anyone else experience this? Any solutions?

(I have posted this question to Slack, they confirmed the behavior a while back but no solution from them so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. Both are valid HTML encodings. You can verify this by decoding them on this [website](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/).

The difference is that the string from IOS also includes an encoding of HTML special characters (like `<`) but the desktop string does not. To address this your app has to first do a URL decoding of the input string and then decode special HTML chars.

The results are:

- Desktop: <#C02MKG1LH|xsd>
- IOS: <#C02MKG1LH|xsd>

Here is a sample code that will decode both strings correctly in PHP:

```
<?php

function decodeInputString($input)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(urldecode($input));
}

$desktop = "%3C%23C02MKG1LH%7Cxsd%3E";
$ios = "%26lt%3B%23C02MKG1LH%7Cxsd%26gt%3B";

$desktop_plain = decodeInputString($desktop);
$ios_plain = decodeInputString($ios);

var_dump($desktop_plain);
var_dump($ios_plain);
```

Comment: On "Desktop: <#C02MKG1LH|xsd>" and "IOS: <#C02GQBT7E|xsd>": those are different right, while they should refer to the same channel ("xsd" in this case) with the same identifier? So, perhaps the encoding is different but irrelevant, but then the channel identifier is different and incorrect.

Comment: You are right. `#xsd` should refer to the same channel ID. However, as I understand it the question was about the different encodings, not the different channel IDs.

Comment: @gero to clarify whether it’s more about channel identifiers or channel id encoding.

Comment: @JochemSchulenklopper The error with the not the same channel IDs was caused by my copy/paste fault. I have updated the question and the answer to make it consistent.

So this answer does address my issue. Thanks @erik-kalkoven!